# find the space left in a triangle with an almost inscribed circle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

is there a way to find the length of the gap that is left if a triangle is almost inscribed by a circle then the top bit of the circle is cut off? (sorry I'm bad at explaining stuff) Here's what I mean: [is there a way to find p?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRe05.png)

Comment: The diagram is ambiguous. Is $\ p\ $ the distance from the triangle's vertex to the circle's circumference or to the chord joining the bits where circle touches the triangle's sides?  Are $\ a\ $ and $\ b\ $ the lengths of the triangle's sides, or the distances from the vertices at the angles $\ x\ $ and $\ y\ $ to the bits where the circle touches the triangle's sides?  I presume that $\ x,y,z,a,b\ $ and $\ c\ $ are all given quantities, but what about the diameter of the circle? Is that also given, or is it unknown?

Comment: the diameter is given.

Answer (score 0):

HINT

$e$ is gap angle balance between side and tangent to circle of length T from A. The gap

$$ g =  T \tan e= \sqrt{p^2-\frac{d^2}{4}}\tan (\pi-x-y- 2 \sin^{-1} \frac{d}{2p})$$

Comment: nice. how did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

In the attached diagram below, AB and AC are tangent to the circle at B and C respectively.  Therefore, triangle ABC is isosceles, and since AD is perpendicular to BC, it must bisect the angle BAC, and its extension must pass through the centre of the circle at O.  Now assuming that $\ p\ $ is the length of AD (this was not completely clear in the diagram cited in the question), then we have
\begin{align}
p&=|\text{AD}|\\
&=|\text{AC}|\cos\frac{z}{2}\\
&=|\text{OC}|\frac{\cos\frac{z}{2}}{\tan\frac{z}{2}}\\
&=\frac{d\cos\frac{z}{2}}{2\tan\frac{z}{2}}\ ,
\end{align}
where $\ d=2|\text{OC}|\ $ is the diameter of the circle.

[image]